# generateKey cpp function

Tags: c++, algorithm, char

Hello i have a problem with one of my functions generateKey() that returns char*.
Its generate the key normal but when i print it i can see something weird.

```
char* aesStartup::generateKey()
{
    const char alphanum[] = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    char newKey[32];
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        newKey[i] = alphanum[rand() % 62];
    cout << newKey;
    return newKey;
}
```

output: u6gWj8dBHxJhEztsHXfE5V3HSvZ2zVNb╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

can someone help me?

Comment: You are missing the `\0` (NUL) character at the end of your chars. At `newKey[31]` needs to be `\0`. Otherwise you print more than you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have *two* serious problems:

1. First of all you seem to have forgotten that strings in C++ are really called ***null-terminated** strings*.

   For an array of characters to be a "string" it needs to be terminated with the `'\0'` character. Which also means a 32-character string needs to have 33 elements.
2. The second problem is that you return a pointer to local data.

   Once the function `generateKey` returns, the life-time of all local variables ends, and pointer to them will become invalid.

You can solve both problems very easily: Stop using character arrays for strings, and start using the C++ standard `std::string` class for all your strings.

---

On another note, you should only call `srand` *once* in your program. And C++ have much better [functions and classes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) for generating random numbers than the C compatibility functions `srand` and `rand`.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `\0 (NUL)` character at the end of your chars. At `newKey[31]` needs to be `\0`. Otherwise you print more than you wish.

In your example the `\0` is within `alphanum` at the end, position 63. So the program reads all memory until it "sees" the `\0`.

Either you switch to use `std::string` which handles this for you, or you need to make sure that all your `char` arrays are null-terminated, by:

- making them one larger than your expected output: `char newKey[33];`

**AND**

- insert `'\0'` at the end: `newKey[32] = '\0';`.